# Get movies that played in all cinemas

Tags: sql-server, query

I stumbled upon a problem of selecting **movies** that have been played in every **cinema** (theaters). All I'm looking for right now is getting the IDs of movies that match this condition, then I will join it on another tables to get additional info. In the attached image you can see, how the main table looks like. **Film** means **Movie** and **Kino** means **Cinema**. Thank you for answers in advance.

I've created this query, but it does not work as intented, because if a cinema (Kino) plays a movie twice, it gets counted in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Program.Film FROM dbo.Program
GROUP BY dbo.Program.Film
HAVING COUNT(dbo.Program.Film) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Kino)
```

[image: The main table]

[image: All the tables]

Comment: Please, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It would help to define what "every cinema" is. Do you have a table somewhere listing them all?

Comment: I don't think you really need this info, as you have to work with the dbo.Program table I attached anyway. Inside dbo.Kino and dbo.Film are not additional info for this query, it's all in dbo.Program - the one attached. dbo.Program.Film and dbo.Program.Kino are foreign keys for the two matching tables.

Comment: Count distinct occurences, i.e. `HAVING COUNT(distinct dbo.Program.Film) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Kino)`

Comment: The attached table includes what movie was played at which cinema and date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery gets all films any kino didn't play by first getting a table off all possible film + kino combinations, left joining all programs in order to filter for rows without a corresponding program record. So the outer query can return any film ID not in that list.

```
select distinct film
from program
where film not in (
select distinct f.film
from (
  select distinct film
  from program
  where film is not null
  ) f
cross join (
  select distinct kino
  from program
  where kino is not null
  ) k
left join program p on f.film = p.film and k.kino = p.kino
where p.film is null)
```

I made a Fiddle to test my query using only the columns I required: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7aff78/3/0

PS: I initially gave an incorrect answer but updated when Nogard told me I was incorrect.

Comment: This won't work as all the values are contained in dbo.Program table, so there's no need for checking null values.

Comment: Have you tried it? I'm doing a self join so any row where cinema (name of the joined table) is null means the film isn't played in a cinema.

Comment: Yup, I tried it. It does not match the table names so I had to rewrite it. But this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for films that have been played in all cinemas = 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Sorry, you're totally right. I've revisited the problem and updated my answer with a correct query and a Fiddle to test it.

Comment: Tysm for the effort!

Answer (score 2):

There are several answer i think lack maintanability and readability, so adding my 5 cents just for the fun of it:
assumption: film plays in kino once

```
SELECT
  film
FROM
  program
GROUP BY
  film
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT kino) = 
    (
      SELECT
        COUNT(1)
      FROM
        kino
    )
```

Comment: Proper method, but unnecessary CTEs (fixed)

Comment: @bbaird yeah, was like 2am, too tired and lazy to clean code. Thanks